# Flutter accessing Uri with authority

Tags: flutter, file, dart, mobile, uri

I'm developing an mobile application that can access a shared folder of Windows to read/write. Currently, my workaround is using Uri package, but the path I'm accessing are authorized (with password), is there any way to access it with Uri IO package or is there any other alternative to recommend to do the following? Below are my code & error.

```
    var createUri = Uri.file(r"\\hostIP\folderName", windows: true);
    var myFolder = Directory.fromUri(createUri);

ERROR:
Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a non-Windows file path from a file URI with an authority
```